# .NET MAUI run the function after a period of time in the background

Tags: maui, background-service, background-task

I am developing an app using .NET MAUI to run on Android and iOS, it's a streaming audio app and I want to add a feature that allows the user to set a timer to turn off the player (from 15 minutes to 2 hours).

Is there a nuget package that fits this need? Or can you suggest a way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to tell me, that you have managed to make a streaming service for Android and IOS, that is running on the background, even when the app is not active? And the last thing left to do is to learn how to do timers?

Comment: Yes, I am using MediaManager package and the audio playback is working fine even when the app is running in the background. I want to implement a timer feature, so that when the time comes, it will call a method like Player.Pause().

Comment: Did you try to use the Timer or the async task to do that? If your app or the service run in the background all the time, what you need to do is write a method to pause the player with a time parameter. And user will pass the time parameter when he set the time.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT, I tried your way and it works on iPhone, however on my Android phone (XiaoMi) it seems that the background service will be killed after about 15 minutes, even though I have set the battery settings to unlimited.

Comment: For the android, you should use the foreground service. The background service will be killed after a little time. Unless it is the system application.

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken, I'm using MediaManager package and it seems to be using foreground service, it seems this is a separate issue for some manufacturers, because I just tested on OnePlus and everything works fine.

Comment: The so problem is the XiaoMi device. Right?

Comment: I am still testing more for Android, currently only iOS is working fine.

Comment: You said that everything worked fine on the OnePlus, so the problem is the special device.